# I have defined max. min. values for my numerical input field in my blazor app. If the user input is out of range, the last value shall be kept. How?

Tags: c#, razor, user-input, blazor-server-side, minmax

My code in my Blazor Server app is as follows:

I am checking the input, on "oninput" event. In my check function I compare the value reg. max and min limits. If they are out of range I can set them to the limit value. That is working.

But I want, if the entered value is out of range, the input value should return immediatly to the last entered correct value. How can I do that?

```
 <td> <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" @bind="@NC_VAR_index"  @onchange=@(e => check_NC_VAR_index(e)) /></td>
 

 protected void check_NC_VAR_index(ChangeEventArgs e)
 {
    if(NC_VAR_index>4) // max value
    {
        TagService.NC_VAR_index[index_] = 4;
    }

    if(NC_VAR_index<1) // min value
    {
        TagService.NC_VAR_index[index_] = 1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does `ChangeEventArgs` contain the previous value?

Comment: How does it compile? From what I know you cannot use `@bind` and `@onchange` on the same element. However, you can save the original value in another variable.